# IoTBrowser proxy setting

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, iot, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to setup web browser on Windows 10 IoT with the sample app IoTBrowser (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/iotbrowser) - this uses simple WebView. It works fine in a simple network without proxy.

I have to use it in a corporate network, so that a proxy setting is crucial. Is there a way to setup proxy for WebView without rewriting the app to HttpWebRequest? This would be problematic, as the app has to compile on ARM platform (for raspberry pi v3) and uses only Universal Windows SDK.

The apps purpose is to show a single web page without any navigation, so the simpler the solution is - the better.